# A Tetrad Puzzle: Find The Key

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, calculation-puzzle

*I made this to test some ideas for a game I'm developing. Feedback would be appreciated.*

---

What is the key?

[image: What's the key?]

Comment: Would the [tag:enigmatic-puzzle] tag be appropriate? Seems like it would.

Comment: This is a great puzzle. Visually very appealing and a nice level of difficult but doable!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Full Solution

**Puzzle #1**

Rules:

> The number on a black triangle is the sum of its adjacents' numbers.

Answer:

> [image]

Key:

> $10 + 25 - 15 = 20$

**Puzzle #2**

Rules:

> We may rotate each pieces so that the corners inside the board are squares and circles. Then, look at the triangles (and its values), sum them to get the key.

Answer:

> **D R R U U**
>  **U L R D D**
>  **R D R R L**
>  **U U L U D**
>  **L D U D U**
>
>  *Note: the holes are*
>  S S C S
>  C S C C
>  C S S C
>  C C S C

Key:

> $-1 \times 7 - 2 \times 4 + 1 \times 8 + 2 \times 6 = 5$

**Puzzle #3** -- Thanks [Dr Xorile](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15942/dr-xorile) for the help! ^^

Rules:

> The word on the right is the antonym of the word on the left.

Answer:

> UP DOWN
>  B(E)GIN END
>  NIC(E) (N)AUGHTY
>  HEA(V)EL H(E)LL
>  VIC(T)ORY DEFEAT
>  PUB(L)IC PR(I)VATE
>  S(W)IM SI(N)K

Key:

> TWELVE - NINE = $3$

**Puzzle #4**

Rules:

> For the numbers, sum the value of black circles. The value is the position from the right side.
>
>  **@**: inverse (black to white, white to black) all circles.
>  **#**: inverse first half of circles.
>  **%**: inverse last half of circles.
>  **$**: add 2 white circles in the end.
>
>  Now we must identify the symbols replacing X, Y, and Z.

Answer:

> As the inverses are commutative, \$X% will be the same as \$%X, this allows us to identify each letters easier.
>  **X** = @
>  **Y** = %
>  **Z** = #
>
>  XY\$X\$ZY = @%\$@\$#% = **WWBBWWBB**

Key:

> $6+5+2+1 = 14$

**Final Puzzle**

> For each colors, we may "mix" the keys from previous puzzles.
>  Then the numbers can be converted to letters (of 26).
>
>  Yellow: 3 = **C**
>  Blue: 20 = **T**
>  Pink: Red + White = 5 + 14 = **S**
>  Purple + 10: Red + Blue + 10 = 5 + 20 + 10 = 35 (9) = **I**
>  Red: 5 = **E**
>  Green: Blue + Yellow = 20 + 3 = **W**
>  Orange: Red + Yellow = 5 + 3 = 8 = **H**
>
>  Anagram it, we will get **WITCHES**, as their words have power.

*I really enjoy solving this puzzle, great work! :D*

Comment: Nice work! CHOYVP CEVINGR and FJVZ FVAX (ROT13)

Comment: Last one is URNIRA URYY

Comment: Which leaves gjryir zvahf avar = guerr

Comment: Yep that's the key, thanks! :D -- now only the last one is unsolved

Comment: A quick and tidy solve. Very nice job! If you have any feedback, I'd love to hear it. Otherwise, thanks for solving it!

Comment: @NigelMNZ It's fun and well-made, I'm impressed. Thanks and good luck for (+ looking forward to) the game! ^^